# How do I copy a file to the root dir in my MVC app as part of a VSTS build pipeline?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to copy a file `test.txt` into the root directory of my MVC application as part of our build process.

We are using `VSTS` and in my build definition I have added a task `Copy Files`

In the task I am setting:

- Source folder to a file in the source eg `My Website/test.txt`
- Contents to `**`
- Target folder to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`

> After the build and release has taken place I expect to be in the root directory of the application, but it isn't?

Can anyone help with what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As Wouter said that the source folder is the folder instead of the file path. What's the result after you changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Source Folder` should point to `MyWebsite`, Contents to `test.txt` or to `*`, not `**`.

`**` is meant for recursive folders and files like this: `**\*`.